# Update object in array if Object Exist else create new one in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is **Streak** Collection and I want to search today date in streaks array if it exists then simply update the question count else create a new Object with the today date.

```
_id : {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
},
streaks :[{
    date :{
        type : Date,
        required : true
    },
    questionCount :{
        type : Number,
        required : true,
        default : 0
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- check if day of `$$NOW` date is new
- if new `$concatArrays` to add the new date with `counter=1`
- else `$map` to update just the counter of the found date

*`$$NOW` is a system variable that has the current date, if you don't want the current date you can put any date you like in "$$NOW" place

*`$dateTrunc` with `unit=day` keeps from the date only the part before day
(ignores time)

Examples are made for 20 November 2021 (change the data if you test them later)
[Test code here(today exists)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7d3QunijV5S)
[Test code here(today doesn't exists)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EgyYQb-UrfK)

```js
update(
{"_id": {"$eq": 1}},
[{"$set": 
    {"new": 
      {"$eq": 
        [{"$filter": 
            {"input": "$streaks",
              "cond": 
              {"$eq": 
                [{"$dateTrunc": {"date": "$$NOW", "unit": "day"}},
                  {"$dateTrunc": {"date": "$$this.date", "unit": "day"}}]}}},
          []]}}},
  {"$set": 
    {"streaks": 
      {"$cond": 
        ["$new",
          {"$concatArrays": 
            ["$streaks", [{"date": "$$NOW", "questionCount": 1}]]},
          {"$map": 
            {"input": "$streaks",
              "in": 
              {"$cond": 
                [{"$eq": 
                    [{"$dateTrunc": {"date": "$$NOW", "unit": "day"}},
                      {"$dateTrunc": {"date": "$$this.date", "unit": "day"}}]},
                  {"$mergeObjects": 
                    ["$$this",
                      {"questionCount": {"$add": ["$$this.questionCount", 1]}}]},
                  "$$this"]}}}]}}}])
```

---

**Edit**
(solution without **$dateTrunc** for MongoDB < 5 )

Query

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y7a9Iq94OWj)

```js
update(
{"_id": 1},
[{"$set": {"date": "$$NOW"}},
  {"$set": {"year": {"$year": "$date"}, "day": {"$dayOfYear": "$date"}}},
  {"$set": 
    {"new": 
      {"$eq": 
        [{"$filter": 
            {"input": "$streaks",
              "cond": 
              {"$and": 
                [{"$eq": [{"$year": "$$this.date"}, "$year"]},
                  {"$eq": [{"$dayOfYear": "$$this.date"}, "$day"]}]}}},
          []]}}},
  {"$set": 
    {"streaks": 
      {"$cond": 
        ["$new",
          {"$concatArrays": 
            ["$streaks", [{"date": "$date", "questionCount": 1}]]},
          {"$map": 
            {"input": "$streaks",
              "in": 
              {"$cond": 
                [{"$and": 
                    [{"$eq": [{"$year": "$$this.date"}, "$year"]},
                      {"$eq": [{"$dayOfYear": "$$this.date"}, "$day"]}]},
                  {"$mergeObjects": 
                    ["$$this",
                      {"questionCount": {"$add": ["$$this.questionCount", 1]}}]},
                  "$$this"]}}}]}}},
 {"$unset": ["date", "year", "day", "new"]}])
```

Comment: This is working fine in MongoDB native driver but in the case of mongoose `Unrecognized expression '$dateTrunc' `. I am currently using the mongoose package. Is there any way to use MongoDB query on the mongoose database connection or an alternative of `$dateTrunc` in mongoose?

Comment: `$dateTrunc` requires mongodb 5, you can do the same with `$year` `$dayOfYear` (2 dates to have both equal) if you are stuck when time i can add one more query for < Mongodb 5

Comment: ok i added one more hope it help, this will work for older MongoDB versions < 5 also.